# Helm, customicing only certain values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy nextcloud with helm and a custom `value.yaml` file that fits my needs. Do i have to specify all values given from the original `value.yaml` or is it possible to only change the values needed, Eg if the only thing I want to change is the host adress my file can look like this:

```yaml
nextlcoud:
    host: 192.168.178.10
```

instead of copying [this file](https://github.com/nextcloud/helm/blob/master/charts/nextcloud/values.yaml) and changing only a few values.

Comment: You should be able to `helm install --set` specific values, or `helm install -f` a YAML file with only the specific values you want to configure.  You can use `helm template` to see what the rendered YAML will look like for a particular configuration.  If you try this, does it work?

Comment: `helm install --set` woks, but `helm install -f` doesn't change the requested value.

Comment: @8bit please tell if the solution was to fix a typo in the file you posted or this typo is only here and you still experiencing the issue.

Comment: @DawidKruk  fixing the typo did the trick, thanks for your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the underlying issue was resolved by the answer of user @Kun Li, I wanted to add some examples when customizing Helm charts as well as some additional reference.

As asked in the question:

> Do i have to specify all values given from the original value.yaml or is it possible to only change the values needed

In short you don't need to specify all of the values. You can change only some of them (like the `host` from your question).
The ways to change the values are following:

> - Individual parameters passed with `--set` (such as `helm install --set foo=bar ./mychart`)
> - A values file if passed into `helm install` or `helm upgrade` with the `-f` flag (`helm install -f myvals.yaml ./mychart`)
> - If this is a subchart, the `values.yaml` file of a parent chart
> - The `values.yaml` file in the chart

You can read more about it by following official `Helm` documentation:

- *[Helm.sh: Docs: Chart template guide: Values files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/)*

> **A side note!**
>
> Above points are set in the order of priority. The first one (`--set`) will have the highest priority to override the values.

---

#### Example

> A side note!
>
> This examples assume that you are in the directory of a pulled Helm chart and you are using Helm v3

Using the `nextcloud` Helm chart used in the question you can set the `nextcloud.host` value by:

- Pulling the Helm chart and editing the values.yaml
- Creating additional `new-values.yaml` to pass it in (the `values.yaml` from Helm chart will be used regardless with lower priority):

  - `$ helm install NAME . -f new-values.yaml`

`new-values.yaml`

```yaml
nextcloud:
  host: 192.168.0.2
```

- Setting the value with `helm install NAME . --set nextcloud.host=192.168.0.2`

You can check if the changes were done correctly by either:

- `$ helm template .` - as pointed by user @David Maze
- `$ helm install NAME . --dry-run --debug`

Comment: Don't you need the `--reuse-values` flag to avoid overwriting what's there? I used `-f` and I overwrote what was there.

Answer (score 1):

you misspelled the `nextcloud` to `nextlcoud` in your value file.